# Deleting old elasticsearch indices Using NestJs

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, nestjs

`green   open   ab_namespacename_namespaceid_appName_appId-2019.02.13   5 
 1   540   0   1.2mb    617kb`

I have a lot of logs in the format of above, I want to delete the old logs (let say which are older than 5 days) by `@timestamp` (in the above log (2019.02.13)) range. I have made the query to delete logs by query.

`let query = {
      index: '*',
      headers: null,
      body: {
        query: {
          filter: {
            '@timestamp': {
              'gte': 'now-5d',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
      try {
      results = await this.elasticSearchClient.deleteByQuery(query);
      console.log('results', results);
      return results;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new LogHubException(e.message, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);`

I have got the below error:

`[parsing_exception] no [query] registered for [@timestamp], with { line=1 & col=42 }`

NOTE: I am using NestJS to call the elasticsearch api, and using elasticsearch[6.4]. I don't want to use elasticsearch-curator.

Answer (score 0):

You query should look like as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-5d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

update the changes accordingly in NestJS code.

Comment: I have modified the query according to your query and got the error: 
`[security_exception] no permissions for [] and User [name=admin, roles=[admin], requestedTenant=null]`.
I have checked all the roles in search-guard, it seems everything is fine.

Comment: Have you provided correct credentials (user with correct role) when creating the `elasticSearchClient`?